# ng-click is not working with windows phone IE browser

Tags: angularjs, html

Anchor tag is smoothly working in everywhere even on IE desktop, but not working on lumia mobile IE browser.

```
<a href="" class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook fb" ng-click="share(row.id)"></a>
```

I am using the function as

```
$scope.share = function (id) {
  //my code is here...
}
```

Comment: Nope. Both are not working.

Comment: I never had any problems with this (especially Desktop), do you have a more complete sample of the page? (maybe the link is hidden oder something else).